# How to handle DWG files in C++

Tags: c++, dwg

I'm working on a project where I will need to import line data from a .dwg file in C++ and am struggling to know where to start. I've had a look at this http://opendesign.com/files/guestdownloads/OpenDesign_Specification_for_.dwg_files.pdf, and I think it is possibly too hardcore for me unless anyone knows of a way of describing, simply, in code the strategy for decoding it? For instance, presumably every single operation would have to be bit wise?

Other than that, I might have to rely on some third-party libraries, but the question is: Are there any such (open source) libraries which are licensed with a permissive license? I can't use copy left code in this project.

To clarify in response to comments, I'm looking for *permissive* licensed libraries (see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_licence). This includes for example MIT and BSD licenses, but not GPL (LGPL would work perhaps, but only if there are exceptions for static linking). And of course public domain would work too. GPL is strongly copyleft, meaning even if you don't alter it, but link to it with separate original code that code *has* to also be licensed under GPL.

Comment: Please be more clear about what types of copyleft you cannot use. Most copyleft licenses are by definition open source. I suspect you mean "public domain."

Comment: Does DXF format fit your needs? Because there are libraries that handles that easier format.

Comment: Dwg is ideal, but yes I think dxf might work. A quick search reveals dxflib, but it's GPL too...

Comment: For the record I looked into libdwg and the lack of documentation is woeful, the make command also failed without reporting any missing dependencies etc. And I was testing libredwg's convert to svg test program (after a successful build albeit with some dubious 'nothing to do' reports and a failed 'sudo make check') and it segfaulted claiming it didn't support the particular file (which they note [http://libreplanet.org/wiki/LibreDWG]) might happen (they want bugs reported). I'm not convinced that they are that much of a solution license preferences ignored anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are plently of DWG libraries available. Try [LibDWG](http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/). It's licensed under the [GNU GPL](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) (i.e. open source). There is also [LibreDWG](http://www.gnu.org/software/libredwg/) which is based on LibDWG, but available directly from the GNU project website. There is an example of using LibreDWG on github that [opens a DWG file, and converts it to an SVG](https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/libredwg/blob/master/examples/testSVG.c).

Reading the file seems pretty straight forward:

```
int error;
Dwg_Data dwg;

error = dwg_read_file(filename, &dwg);

if (!error)
{
    model_xmin = dwg_model_x_min(&dwg);
    model_ymin = dwg_model_y_min(&dwg);
    double dx = (dwg_model_x_max(&dwg) - dwg_model_x_min(&dwg));
    double dy = (dwg_model_y_max(&dwg) - dwg_model_y_min(&dwg));
    double scale_x = dx / (dwg_page_x_max(&dwg) - dwg_page_x_min(&dwg));
    double scale_y = dy / (dwg_page_y_max(&dwg) - dwg_page_y_min(&dwg));
    //...
}

dwg_free(&dwg);
```

Comment: He said that cannot use a copy left licensed library.

Comment: He said open source with permission. GPL is open source with permission.

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a new opensource library (under MIT license, so you can use it completely for free, unlike libredwg/lidwg/ODA Teigha) to work with CAD (DWG/DXF) files. Now it handles DWG R15 (2000) pretty well, so you can try to use it. There is no stable release yet, but any testing will help a lot for project.

Link:[libopencad github](https://github.com/sandyre/libopencad)

Installation is descibed in README.md
Usage is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
# include "lib/opencad_api.h"

// returns nullptr on fail. GetLastErrorCode() returns an error code.
CADFile *pCADFile = OpenCADFile( pszCADFilePath,
                                      CADFile::OpenOptions::READ_ALL ); 

const CADHeader& header = pCADFile->getHeader ();
header.print (); // prints CAD Header variables.
cout << endl;

const CADClasses& classes = pCADFile->getClasses ();
classes.print (); // prints custom CAD classes
cout << endl;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < pCADFile->getLayersCount (); ++i )
{
    CADLayer &layer = pCADFile->getLayer (i);
    cout << "Layer #" << i << " contains "
         << layer.getGeometryCount () << " geometries" << endl;

    for ( size_t j = 0; j < layer.getGeometryCount (); ++j )
    {
        unique_ptr<CADGeometry> geom(layer.getGeometry (j));

        if ( geom == nullptr )
            continue;

        switch ( geom->getType() ) // returns GeometryType enum.
        {
            case CADGeometry::CIRCLE:
                CADCircle * poCADCircle = ( CADCircle* ) geom.get();
                std::cout << poCADCircle->getPosition().getX() << std::endl;
                std::cout << poCADCircle->getPosition().getY() << std::endl;
                std::cout << poCADCircle->getPosition().getZ() << std::endl;
                break;
            // any other geometry type you need.
        }
    }
}
```