# Teigha Win32 sample

Tags: c++, winapi

everyone

I'm seeking for pure Win32 simple application that using Teigha library. I need in simple Win32 application that renders dwg file. I need in something like SingleDoc app. I don't need in MFC, Qt etc., just pure Win32. I looked in Teigha samples, but there are just MFC, Qt. Where can I find simple barebone for such app?

Thanks

Comment: Probably the reason why you don't see Win32 examples is that it is more difficult to write a mock GUI in Win32 to demonstrate the library, and easier to do this in MFC or Qt.

Comment: This isn't going to be easy to answer unless you have a link to the library and to the samples.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, there are just MFC and Qt samples. But I'm seeking for just Win32 example. May be there is someone who encountered with same problem and solved it and can provide me with some idea.

Comment: What **is** your problem? An MFC sample easily translates to pure Win32. Since the framework is entirely insignificant in illustrating the capabilities of the Teigha library, I really don't know, what you are looking for. As far as the library is concerned, rendering code is identical between MFC and a Win32 application.

Comment: I'm looking for pure Win32 simple sample as I specified in my post. But if I can generate clear, not very sophisticated code from MFC sample, then this idea might to be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateWindowEx() and RegisterClass should get you started, plenty of examples out there for full code, but you just need a simple window to draw lines on.  Reading the dwg file is little more tricky (not sure what the library you referenced is since you provided no links to it and my search ability at work is limited).

Here are some links to reading in dwg files:
[How to handle DWG files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597111/how-to-handle-dwg-files-in-c)

This might be what you're looking for, though it looks MFC it would be quite easy to re-code in pure Win32 with a little work:
http://www.codeforge.com/article/47732